# asp.net core - form values return null

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-core

Passing department and title models for use data in selectbox and passing employee model for save data from user. tring to pass values from partial view but in controller values return null.

partial view:

```
@model (List<Department> Departments, List<Title> Titles, Employee e)

    <form class="g-3" asp-action="CreateEmployee" asp-controller="Employees" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="Name" class="form-label">İsim</label>
                    <input asp-for="e.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        İsim alanı boş bırakılamaz.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Tek Form</button>
    </form>
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult CreateEmployee()
        {
            HR_ManagementContext context = new HR_ManagementContext();
            var departments = context.Departments.ToList();
            var titles = context.Titles.ToList();

            var models = (departments, titles, new Employee());

            return View(models);
        }
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("CreateEmployee");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @Jackdaw his answer also working too.

I found an alternative

in Controller you can bind model:

```
public IActionResult CreateEmployee([Bind(Prefix = "Item3")]Employee employee)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CreateEmployee");
}
```

Item3 is the prefix of tuple model.

```
@model (List<Department> Departments, List<Title> Titles, Employee e)
```

- Department = Item1
- Titles = Item2
- Employee = Item3

Answer (score 1):

Set the `name` attribute in the `input` tag:

```cs
<input asp-for="e.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="Name", name="employee.Name">
```

The second solution is to use model name `item3` generated by the MVC:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee item3)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CreateEmployee");
}
```

Comment: thx, its worked! but i have a question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133766/one-of-the-form-post-fields-returns-null-net-core-mvc  i saw this and its not recomment using name and id with asp-for (because its override) so in this example whats the point of using name? why asp-for not working?

Comment: @Selcukusu: Right, but because of you are using the [tuple type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) the model element names will be `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3`. And this will prevent from the MVC parser to work properly. Therefore, the best solution is to use the strongly typed view instead of the tuple type.